# Pydev + Google App Engine + Eclipse = dev_appserver terminates right on

Tags: google-app-engine, pydev

i've been a happy user for pydev, eclipse and gae.

Now i've changed my computer and reinstalled the latest jee eclipse, pydev and gae. As usual, I configure my pydev gae project (I use App Engine Modules), have it launched by the eclipse debugger.

The issue is that as soon as I launch a cron task through the admin interface (localhost:8000/cron), every thread terminates and the dev_appserver ends (exit value : 137)

Everything run smooth when launching dev_appserver.py by hand and with pycharm (i'd like to keep using pydev!)

### versions

```
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.33
app-engine-python 1.9.12
eclipse 4.4.1
pydev 3.8.0.201425
```

### Debug windows content

```
<terminated>xxxx xxxx (1) [PyDev Google App Run]    
    <terminated>dev_appserver.py    
    dev_appserver.py    
    dev_appserver.py    
    dev_appserver.py    
    <terminated, exit value: 137>dev_appserver.py
```

### console ouput

```
 pydev debugger: starting (pid: 20240)
 INFO     2014-10-15 10:27:19,522 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at:        http://localhost:34966
 INFO     2014-10-15 10:27:19,523 dispatcher.py:174] Starting dispatcher running at: http://localhost:8080
 INFO     2014-10-15 10:27:19,553 dispatcher.py:186] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8081
 INFO     2014-10-15 10:27:19,586 dispatcher.py:186] Starting module "static-backend" running at: http://localhost:8082
 INFO     2014-10-15 10:27:19,589 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
 pydev debugger: starting (pid: 20264)
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but with adding a map-reduce job. Same thing, the app server just terminates without any error, but I can launch the same thing via command line dev_appserver. Did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: unfortunately, no I stopped used pydev and switched to the evil, paying, closed source pycharm (which runs really nice btw). What a shame to install closed source software on my machine :-(

Comment: Same issue for me too. GAE 1.9.17 / Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 / PyDev 3.9.1.201501081637 / Java 8 Update 31 / Mac OSX 10.10.2